# C How to compute thickness of a layer when object in material

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I was making a school project and I found myself in a tight spot. I have a block of material with given size (cube, 100 000 units) that has "bubbles" inside. I need to cut it to plates with equal volume. I need a way to compute a single layer with only the bubbles position and radius. Bubbles never interlap and they are always completely inside the block. I was told that this formula might help:

[image: \int_{x=1-h}^1 \pi(1-x^2)dx = \pi(h-\frac13 + \frac {(1-h)^3}3)]

I am thankful for any useful information and please do not bother writing complete code, just the basic principle will be more than enough for me. Thank you

EDIT: I have found this implementation and I am currently trying to convert it to C and use its principle in my code:
http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~dmarino/progcontests/mysols/worldfinals/2015/

Comment: Why are you posting this on a programming site? It looks like you are very far from being able to write a program.

Comment: Are bubbles spherical by the way?

Comment: Could you clarify the statement, "I need a way to compute a single layer with only the bubbles position and radius"? Are you given this information about one bubble, or all the bubbles? What is the result of computing a single layer?

Comment: @KaleoBrandt. Given the position and size of all the bubbles, where would you make cuts so that the cube is divided into n pieces of equal volume?

Comment: @KaleoBrandt. This is fairly non-trivial, especially if you want a fast solution.

Comment: This is like problem D - ACM ICPC World Final 2015. Check this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftJM6aNQzEA

Comment: I am sorry if my question was wrong in some way, I have actually writing a program is not an issue for me, its the math behind this particular project I have problem with. Bubbles are spherical and I need to cut a layer off the material so its volume will be of certain size. And yes I need to cut this block into layers of equal volume, I just figured if I am able to make one layer, I can use the same code to make more.

Comment: Eduardo thank you, please post it as an answer so I can upvote it, it really helped a lot.

Comment: ^^This happens when you remake your comment multiple times and dont read it afterwards... /facepalm/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question, not a programming question. Try https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: ??? ugoren I asked about using the aforementioned formula to write a code for computing a volume of an object, I know it is related to math, but how can you say it is not a programming question? If I just had to solve it myself I would have been done long ago...

Comment: Sounds like you want to think about Eshelby inclusions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eshelby%27s_inclusion and Eshelby stress tensor: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020768306002927

Comment: duffymo I am sorry but I do not see how elasticity is related to this problem...

Comment: Eshelby inclusions can treat materials with voids in them.  It's a more general approach.  When I see someone say "I was told this formula might help" it suggests that the person has no idea what they're doing.  Consider this a bit of education.

Comment: There are lots of numerical integration algorithms out there.  The volume of the layer with holes is obviously equal to the volume of the layer without voids minus the total volume of the voids.  You don't say anything about the distribution, whether or not the void radius varies, etc.  But given those the calculation should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

well I can convert that formula to C for you if it helps

```
#include <math.h>
double Func(double h)
{
    double ret = C_PI*(h - (1.0/3.0) + (pow(1.0-h, 3)/3.0);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that is not really what I had in mind, imagine this: Cube with a given size has bubbles is it, you know where and how big bubbles are, how do you compute a volume of a layer? - in this example I switched looking for thickness to looking for volume

Comment: no idea - this is a c programming site not a math site. Give me the algorithm - i will give you the code

Comment: Thank you, if you check out the oroginal post I added a link to a code I found, looks like our teacher got lazy and flat out copied that competition.